# Why does VS think this statement is always true?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement

I have this if statement -

```
if (!((main.property == 1)||(main.property == 2)))
{
   ...
}
```

main.property is a byte which is either 0, 1, 2 or 98.

Visual studios says that this statement is always true but I can't see why?

If the property is 1 or 2 shouldn't this be false.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Added code

file1.cs

```
private void Upload(DataSet ds)
{
    Main main = CreateMain(ds); //This is tested and works correctly
    if(ValidateDate(main))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

file2.cs

```
internal static bool ValidateData(Main main, ...)
{
    if (!((main.property == 1)||(main.property == 2)))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Edit: Added code

If I do this the error goes away -

```
internal static bool ValidateData(Main main, ...)
{
     main.property = 0; //Or = any number
     if (!((main.property == 1)||(main.property == 2)))
     {
          ...
     }
}
```

I'm guessing VS thinks it isn't initialised but I am 100% positive it is.

Comment: If you happen to initialise `main.property` in the same method, could you show the code for that, too? My guess is that VS assumes the value 0 for `main.property`.

Comment: Are you sure that's your *exact* code? Please post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The whole main object is passed to the method. The property is set elsewhere though but the value comes from an external file so can vary.

Comment: Just a minor unrelated nitpick, why not use demorgans laws and rewrite the condition as (main.property != 1 && main.property != 2)? At least I think that would be a bit more readable :)

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: @wasatz That's pretty subjective; I think either way is fine.

Comment: Have you tried to prove visual studio wrong, i.e. debug it, ensure main.property is 1 or 2 and see if the expresion evaluates to true.

Comment: @wasatz - Thank you for the comment but i think either is ok. I read my way as - if not (1 or 2). Pretty readable i think.

Comment: My main readability problem is with the superfluous ()'s.

Comment: @Ben - The 'program' is actually on of several modules in the whole and can't currently compile. The error is only in the ide so i don't know if it would stop it compiling.

Comment: Is it about VS or .Net Compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this little program to check it out:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test(0);
        test(1);
        test(2);
        test(3);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void test(int p)
    {
        bool b1 = (!((p == 1) || (p == 2)));
        bool b2 = (p != 1 && p != 2);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", b1, b2, b1 == b2);
    }
}
```

It seems that Constantin is right in his transcription, but neither expression is always true or always false.

Comment: @fearof - The author of a now deleted answer on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Step through your code to find out what main.property value is.

I had a similar issue and it was because the value was <strike>null</strike> the default value.

Comment: Main would apear to be an int, which is not nullable.

Comment: According to the OP its a byte.
Which can't be null.
Thinking of byte arrays. Fail.
Clarifying post.

Comment: I hope bytes can be null. Doesn't byte? mean it's nullable.

Comment: A C# byte is an integral value type and value types cannot contain the null value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx .

"byte?" is a nullable type  but is not exactly the same as a "byte" type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you claim that main.property is a byte which is either 0, 1, 2 or 98, you should assert that condition at the beginning of that method as such:

```
internal static bool ValidateData(Main main, ...)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(main.property == 0 || main.property == 1 || main.property ==2 || main.property == 98);
    if (!((main.property == 1)||(main.property == 2)))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```